# CSS making a :active toggled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am trying to create a web presentation and wanted to a add a little Animation of 2 Halfes which moves up and down on a Click (which works so far) but i also want them to stay there after the click.

[standard looking version http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/3ozt9kfyr08.jpg](http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/3ozt9kfyr08.jpg)
[0.75 seconds after the click on the logo in the middle http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/2lpdyoktws6.jpg](http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/2lpdyoktws6.jpg)
[after the animation http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/18cd9xfjg21.jpg](http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/18cd9xfjg21.jpg)

This is my Code for that: HTML

```
    <body>
    <a href="#" id="btn_logo" onclick="return false"> <div id="animation">      
            <div id="logo"> </div>  
            <div id="up"> </div>
            <div id="down"> </div>
        </div></a>
```

and then made the animation with:

```
#btn_logo:active #up
```

and

```
#btn_logo:active #down
```

How could i make the animation toggled after it ended?

Comment: Can you show your CSS for the animation? The CSS animation definition is generally to run the animation once unless specified to longer.

Comment: You will need Javascript to monitor the event. Since you need JS to do this, I would just use jQuery's animate method since it has its own completion callback.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you should do is have it animate on a CSS class, and then simply add or remove a CSS class on click.

Like so: https://jsfiddle.net/8troo8bw/1/

(or so with your exact html): https://jsfiddle.net/8troo8bw/2/

The key here being the animation:

```
#up, #down {
  background: #000;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:25px;
  transition: top 0.25s;
}

#up.moveUp {
  top: 25px;
}
#down.moveDown {
  top: 100px;
}
```

And the relevent JS to add the class:

```
$('#click').on('click', function(){
  $('#up').addClass('moveUp');
  $('#down').addClass('moveDown');
});
```

Comment: Since i haven't made a lot of expierence with js so far how exactly do i add this?

I seperate the div "animation" from "up" and down" and then i connect the onclick with the js code so that it adds the class for the animation?

Comment: You can keep your wrapper div, if you want to, that doesn't matter. The Javascript only is there to add the other CSS class to the elements so that it activates the CSS animation.

Comment: @MarcelSchulz Here is an example using the exact same HTML as you: https://jsfiddle.net/8troo8bw/2/ (just click on the bars)

Comment: How would i readjust my CSS?
right now i have #up and #down and ##btn_logo:active #down and ##btn_logo:active #up             
Do i need to make the css as you did?

Comment: @MarcelSchulz Take off the `:active` pseudo-selector. The important part of the solution is simply that you have another class that will modify the property you are trying to animate, and you are then adding that class.

Comment: Thank you! i understood what i did know and why and it works like a charm! thank you so much

Comment: Without using javascript you could do this: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dv2wfom7/).

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#animation').on('click', function() {
      $('.up,.down').addClass('animated');
    });
  });
```

```css
#animation {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: yellow;
}

.logo {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.up {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 0;
  background: green;
}

.down {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: blue;
}

.up.animated {
  bottom: 100%;
  top: -50%;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

.down.animated {
  top: 100%;
  bottom: -50%;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="animation">      
    <div class="up"> </div>
    <div class="down"> </div>
    <div class="logo"> </div>  
</div>
```